# Cant send video blob to server using Laravel and Vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, video-streaming

I am trying to create a live interview video network. The problem i am currently facing is that when i try to save my video file locally it saves it.. But when i have deployed this code to AWS the same request gives me null file. This cant be a code issue since i am using the same code block locally. I am using two separate code blocks for my front end and backend. I am usin vuejs as frontend and laravel as backend.

**Vuejs is not the one integrated within laravel.**

This is my request payload :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryls1UXJA318waDqAx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url"

blob:https://finlinkpro.com/81c5c11b-2221-4d39-b192-6223fd745029
------WebKitFormBoundaryls1UXJA318waDqAx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video"

video_537203.webm
------WebKitFormBoundaryls1UXJA318waDqAx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blob"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: video/webm


------WebKitFormBoundaryls1UXJA318waDqAx--
```

Even when i simplye dump my request in backend i get null.

> Note : www.finlinkpro.com is my frontend url and my backend runs on
>   www.backend.finlinkpro.com

I cant seem to understand how to even debug this issue.

Comment: did you check with dd($request->blob); in your post action?

Comment: i dont see how would that work actually.. its causing the same problem that i was having.. null is what i am getting in blob as well. i suspect it has something to do with server configuration